# Swashbuckle ignores parameter order

Tags: c#, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have an api which targets netcoreapp2.2 using Swashbuckle v4.0.1. The api has an HttpPut endpoint which has a signature like the following:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put([FromBody] string mycontent, int id)
        {
        }
```

where the value from the request body (mycontent) is listed first in the signature and the id is listed second.  When I look at the json generated for this, the order the parameters are listed in the parameters section matches the signature (mycontent first and id second).

```
"parameters": [
   {
     "name": "mycontent",
     "in": "body",
     "required": false,
     "schema": {
       "type": "string"
     }
   },
   {
     "name": "id",
     "in": "path",
     "required": true,
     "type": "integer",
     "format": "int32"
   }
],
```

After upgrading to net6.0 and Swashbuckle 6.3.0, the generated json has the id first and mycontent second. Essentially ignoring the order in which they are specified in the signature.

```
"parameters": [
  {
    "in": "path",
    "name": "id",
    "required": true,
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int32"
  },
  {
    "in": "body",
    "name": "mycontent",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
],
```

This causes a breaking change in the client code that has been generated from this json using swaggergen as it is using the order in which the parameters are listed in the json to build the argument list for the client method.

```
put(string mycontent, int id)
```

vs

```
put(int id, string mycontent)
```

Is there a way to reproduce the old json generation behavior?

Comment: I couldnt find an annotation that could help you. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

But if you think its a bug then it would be worth adding an issue to the github repo.